# Percolate data through properties

Tags: c#, .net, events, event-handling

I've got a class with a list of properties, and the properties themselves have a list of properties. I need the "grandchild"- property to be able to request data from it's parent's parent (sorry for the confusing terms - there's no inheritance here). To clarify:

```
class ClassA
{
 list<ClassB> Children
 var SomeOtherProperty
}

class ClassB
{
list<ClassC> Grandchildren
}

class ClassC
{
 var GetSomeOtherProperty()
 {
  ...
 }
}
```

The data may change during run time so I can't just pass it once and be done with it, I gotta be able to get it dynamically.

I could always pass the parent all the way down to the grandchild in the ctors, but I was taught it's a bad practice, so I'd rather avoid it.

I've been reading about passing data back/downwards via events using mutable EventArguments- I'm wondering if that'd be an OK solution for what I've got (I'll need to do it twice each time- sort of chase the tail of the first eventarg). Are there any pitfalls I need to be aware of?

Do I have any other options for this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: the name children, parent & grandparent are a little misleading in your question. Are they derivatives ? So is it the situation that `ClassC` extends `ClassB` And `ClassB` extends `ClassA` ? I guess there are composed within one & another but not linked through inheritance. I'm I correct ?

Comment: @Kapoor correct. They're just properties- I'll edit to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you can use the design pattern composite. First, create a base class 'note' with a list of notes for the children and a virtual method 'DoAction'. Then derive all other classes from this class and override the method with own implementation.

Now you can build up a tree of notes and do a traversal on all of it childs. For each of them, call 'DoAction'.

Hope you get the idea...

Answer (score 0):

Since classes A, B & C are not liked via inheritance, therefore, I would like to avoid any direct wiring between these classes as it will make the design a little complicated as the system would evolve.

Moreover, since class B has nothing to do with the data, I dont want it to get effected by it.

Therefore, I would like to take out the communicate via a separate route to keep the classes loosely coupled - [image]

here is a sample code to explain my idea  -

```
       public interface  IPublisher 
       {
         event EventHandler OperationOccurred;
       }

      class ClassA : IPublisher
      {

          List<ClassB> Children;

          event EventHandler OperationOccurred;

         public ClassA()
          {
              BroadCaster.Instance.RegisterPublisher(this);
          }

          protected virtual void OnOperationOccurred()
          {
              if (OperationOccurred != null)
                  OperationOccurred(this, new EventArgs());
          }

      }

        class ClassB
        {
            List<ClassC> Grandchildren;
        }

        class ClassC
        {
          public ClassC()
            {
                BroadCaster.Instance.BroadCastNotificaiton += Instance_OperationOccurred;
            }

          void Instance_OperationOccurred(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
              throw new NotImplementedException();
          }
        }



    /// <summary>
    /// A singleton class ... Like a  single braodcast tower just one in the city
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class BroadCaster
    {
        public static BroadCaster Instance { get; private set; }

        //Static constructor
        static BroadCaster()
        {
            Instance = new BroadCaster();
        }

        // private constructor 
        private BroadCaster(){}

        public event EventHandler BroadCastNotificaiton;

        public void RegisterPublisher(IPublisher publisher)
        {
            publisher.OperationOccurred += Publisher_OperationOccurred;
        }

        void Publisher_OperationOccurred(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.BroadCastNotificaiton != null)
                this.BroadCastNotificaiton(sender, e);
        }



    }
```

I have implemented broadcaster a singleton object, but all I want to convey is a single point of communication.

Hope it helps.